# Include Swagger-UI code blocks in the info section

Tags: swagger-ui

It appears that Swagger UI is ripping out and messing with things that look like HTML tags even when inside markdown triple-backtick delimited code blocks!

I have written

````
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My Title
  description: |
    Hello here is some Python code
    ```
      def hello():
          return "hello"
    ```
    and here is some HTML
    ```
      <body>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <script>x = 1</script>
      </body>

    ```
    That is all
````

Unfortunately Swagger-UI renders this as
[image]

I am not complaining about the fact that it did not use highlight.js in the markdown; it is after all an open source project and that can be fixed. However, I noticed it stripped out the HTML tags, which is fine, except that when I tried to escape the angle brackets like this:

````
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My Title
  description: |
    Hello here is some Python code
    ```
      def hello():
          return "hello"
    ```
    and here is some HTML
    ```
      &lt;body>
      &lt;p>Hello</p>
      &lt;script>x = 1</script>
      &lt;/body>

    ```
    That is all
````

then the tool comes back with

[image]

Does anyone know how I can defeat Swagger-UI and show an HTML code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger UI v. 3 displays HTML tags in code blocks correctly:

[image: Markdown code block in API description displayed in Swagger UI]

Here's the YAML that I used:

````
  description: |
    Hello here is some Python code
    ```
    def hello():
      return "hello"
    ```
    and here is some HTML
    ```
    <body>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <script>x = 1</script>
    </body>
    ```
    That is all
````

**Note:** If your code block has styling issues as shown below, upgrade to Swagger UI 3.22.0+ or Swagger Editor 3.6.26+. Older versions had a [CSS issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3117) that was fixed in the mentioned versions.

[image: Code blocks in API description in Swagger UI]

Comment: Nice. This seems a problem with Swagger-UI v.2 then. I was sticking with v2 for now, not only because of the much better CSS, but because of the known issue "Relative path support for external files is not implemented." (mentioned on the GitHub home page for the project.)

Comment: @RayToal: Code block styling issue has been fixed in recent versions of Swagger UI 3.x.